# Fastest way to remove a lot of keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a large dictionary, (actually, a `defaultdict`) with tens of millions of key-value pairs (strings : integers).

I want to remove about half of the key/value pairs, based on a simple condition (e.g. `value > 20`) on the values.

What is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: Could you be a little clearer about exactly what the condition is? Is it a regular expression on the keys, or a condition like `"foo" in key`, or whether the key is 16 bytes, or …

Comment: If you're doing this often enough that you really do need the fastest way to do it, you may want to change data structures, or maybe even write your own class that's optimized for this case. From a quick check, using Cocoa's dictionaries and filter methods (via PyObjC) is anywhere from 8x slower to 4x faster for different cases. (I'm not suggesting that you use NSDictionary, just pointing out how much difference you can get makes.)

Comment: One more possibility: Don't actually remove them, just mark them as removed (e.g., set them to None). That should make this step blazingly fast. Of course it means all your actual uses of the dictionary will be more complex and slower (because you have to check for None before using the value), and you'll be wasting a lot of long-term memory, so for most use-cases this is definitely a bad solution. But if removing items is actually your bottleneck, it could conceivably be worth doing.

Comment: @abarnert if I could afford not to remove them, then I wouldn't! I need to make as much free memory as possible for a subsequent part of the program.

Comment: Well, as I said it was a bad solution for most use-cases (which is also why I wrote it as a comment rather than an answer), but it was worth checking. But that raises the question: why do you need to make as much free memory as possible for a subsequent part of the program? Are you hitting the VM size limit or thrashing swap or something when you run that later part of the program?

Comment: @abarnert Yeah, thrashing swap :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an iterator-based regeneration of the dict is a good approach:

```
newdict = dict((k,v) for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 20)
```

or

```
newdict = {k: v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 20}
```

in Python 2.7.

Note that you have to be careful with `d = {k: v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 20}`. Instead you should invoke

```
d.clear()
d.update({k: v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 20})
```

This way, old references to the data in `d` will also refer to the filtered data.

**Edit:**

Let's compare three methods discussed in this thread via benchmark:

The result obviously depends on the proportion of the dictionary to be "deleted" (which is maybe unpredictable but only the thread opener knows). It may also highly depend on the activity of the garbage collection, which is by default [switched off](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit) during `timeit`. It is switched off in order to reduce noise in the measurement. However, this can entirely change the ranking of the methods. Let's have a look:

Benchmark code upfront:

```
from timeit import timeit

n = 2
N = "10**7"
mod = "9999999"
gc = "False"
print "N: %s; mod: %s; garbage collection: %s" % (N, mod, gc)

setup ="""
N = %s
mod = %s
d = {x:1 for x in xrange(N)}
if %s:
    gc.enable()""" % (N, mod, gc)

t = timeit(
'd = {k:v for k, v in d.iteritems() if not k % mod}',
setup=setup,
number=n)
print "%s times method 1 (dict comp): %.3f s" % (n, t)

t = timeit(
'''
for k, v in d.items():
    if k % mod:
        del d[k]
''',
setup=setup,
number=n)
print "%s times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): %.3f s" % (n, t)

t = timeit('''
removekeys = [k for k, v in d.iteritems() if k % mod]
for k in removekeys:
    del d[k]
''',
setup=setup,
number=n)
print "%s times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): %.3f s" %(n, t)
```

**Case 1 (none of the items of the dictionary are filtered out):**

*Garbage collection enabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 1; garbage collection: True
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 4.701
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 15.782
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.024
```

*Garbage collection disabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 1; garbage collection: False
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 4.701
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 4.268
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.027
```

**Case 2 (half of the items of the dictionary are filtered out):**

*Garbage collection enabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 2; garbage collection: True
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 3.449 s
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 12.862 s
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.765 s
```

*Garbage collection disabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 2; garbage collection: False
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 3.395 s
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 4.175 s
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.893 s
```

**Case 3 (almost all of the items of the dictionary are filtered out):**

*Garbage collection enabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 9999999; garbage collection: True
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 1.217 s
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 9.298 s
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.141 s
```

*Garbage collection disabled:*

```
N: 10**7; mod: 9999999; garbage collection: False
2 times method 1 (dict comp): 1.213 s
2 times method 2 (key deletion within for loop over d.items()): 3.168 s
2 times method 3 (key deletion after list comp): 2.141 s
```

Measured on 64bit Python 2.7.3 on Linux 2.6.32-34-generic on a Xeon E5630 with 24 GB memory. Peak memory usage below 10 % (monitored via top).

**Conclusion**

1. The performance of method 1 and 3 is independent of the state of the garbage collection.
2. Method 2 is significantly slowed down by garbage collection. Method 1 and 3 are always faster, except for the case with disabled garbage collection an no item being filtered out.
3. If most items are expected to be filtered out, use method 1 (the dictionary comprehension). If you expect to throw out up to half (or maybe even more, finer benchmarking required) of the number of keys, then use method 3.

I'd go for method 1 in any case, because it is cleaner code than method 3 and the difference in performance is not large. But that's entirely up to you.

Comment: With Python 2.7 you may as well use a dict comprehension.

Comment: Can you tell us: (1) what OS you're on, (2) whether you're using 32- or 64-bit Python, (3) what the peak memory usage is for each test (you need to split it into two separate scripts for that), and (4) whether method 2 is triggering your system to page out memory to swap? Because from what I'm seeing, method 2 is significantly faster, except that in 64-bit Python it can run through enough temporary memory to cause swapping, making things an order of magnitude (linux) or two (Mac) slower instead.

Comment: Yeah, peak memory use is also an important consideration.

Comment: Use items() instead of iteritems() if using Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

```
dict((k,v) for k,v in original_dict.iteritems() if condition)
```

This creates a new dictionary based on your condition, in a memory-friendly (due to `iteritems` and generators) and efficient way (not a whole lot of function/method calls).

Answer (score 2):

For reference:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit as t
    # Create a new dict with a dict comprehension
>>> t('x={k:v for k, v in x.iteritems() if v % 2}', 'x={x:x for x in xrange(10**7)}', number=30)
100.02150511741638
    # Delete the unneeded entries in-place
>>> t('''for k, v in x.items():
...   if v % 2 != 0:
...     del x[k]''', 'x={x:x for x in xrange(10**7)}', number=30)
89.83732604980469
```

(I'm assuming the speed of the modulus == 0 comparison is on the same order as < 20, but that's not really relevant to these tests.) They are about the same order of magnitude for a very large dict, but I guess the in-place is a little faster.

Comment: Have you checked equality of both outcomes?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke yeah, but then I realized OP asked for *values* and changed the test without making the values meaningful. Will update shortly as soon as these really long tests finish :)

Comment: @kojiro: I got completely different timing results. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: I think this is going to depend primarily on how often the two methods end up rehashing—which is something that's hard to predict, impossible to control, and quite possibly very different on different people's systems…

Comment: @abarnert, others, if I make this cw will you upload your own numbers? (Using the same script, please, so as not to confuse the issue.)

Comment: OK, here's something odd. If I reduce the dict size to 3M, the times are 16.3724858761 vs. 13.3722991943, and in-place surprisingly uses a little more peak memory (although I didn't get an exact measure). But at the original 10M, it was 69.3220782279 vs. something well over 4 minutes before I managed to ssh in and killall python, because my machine was swap-thrashing so badly it wouldn't even respond to cmd-opt-esc. (This is on a mid 2011 MacBook Pro i7, 4GB RAM, no SSD, OS X 10.8.1, stock Apple Python 2.7.2.) It may be that "a little more" memory was just enough to push it over a cliff.

Comment: Folllowup: Up to around 3M, the second version is consistently about 20% faster, but uses about 20% more memory. Beyond this, the timing stays consistent, but the memory ratio increases rapidly, until around 9M the second version is using over 4GB (vs. 948MB) and the whole computer slows to a crawl. However, if I force Python to run in 32-bit mode, the speed difference is only 8%, but the 20% memory ratio stays constant.

Comment: I think we now got the right conclusions. Have a look at my answer. It turns out that 'your way' of in-place deletion is highly dependent on garbage collection, which is why there was this large difference between both of our benchmarks. @KeithRandall 's deletion method is faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with making a new `dict`:

```
dict((k, v) for k,v in D.iteritems() if k != "foo")
```

If you really want to modify the original:

```
removekeys = [k for k, v in D.iteritems() if k == "foo"]
for k in removekeys: del D[k]
```

I'm not sure these are the fast-*est*, but they should be fast.

Comment: Your second solution is faster than the first one in case there is not much to delete from the dictionary (as expected, cf. the benchmark in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

As of python3 you need to use *iter()* instead of *iteritems()*, since this function got removed apparently. Just leaving this here, because I got an error using the above-mentioned code.